# Trend line and slope (R)

Tags: r

I'm trying to study this protein interaction net. I need to do a plot of the degree distribution of the edges (last lines of the code), but I'm not able to make a trend line and the slope (last line of the code). Can someone help me please?

```
    install.packages("igraph")
    library("igraph")
    tfile<-tempfile()
    download.file("http://pdg.cnb.uam.es/pazos/tmp/Yeast_int.txt", tfile)
    datosraw <- subset(read.delim(tfile, sep="\t", header=F, stringsAsFactors = F), !is.na(V3) & V3!="" & V3!="METHOD")
    names(datosraw)<-c("orf1","orf2","method")
    datos<-split(datosraw,datosraw$method)
    df.y2h <- graph.data.frame(d = datos$Y2H[1:5125,c(1,2)], directed = FALSE)
    deg.dist.df.y2h <- degree.distribution(df.y2h)
    plot(deg.dist.df.y2h, xlab="k", ylab="P(k)", main="Y2H")
    plot(deg.dist.df.y2h, xlab="log k", ylab="log P(k)", main="Y2H", log = "xy", asp)
    abline(lm(deg.dist.df.y2h))
```

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

You are placing `abline` on the plot done on `log10-log10` scale. Here's one way of doing it

Your code

```
library("igraph")
tfile<-tempfile()
download.file("http://pdg.cnb.uam.es/pazos/tmp/Yeast_int.txt", tfile)
datosraw <- subset(read.delim(tfile, sep="\t", header=F, stringsAsFactors = F), !is.na(V3) & V3!="" & V3!="METHOD")
names(datosraw)<-c("orf1","orf2","method")
datos<-split(datosraw,datosraw$method)
df.y2h <- graph.data.frame(d = datos$Y2H[1:5125,c(1,2)], directed = FALSE)
```

The rest can be wrapped in to a helper function

```
plot_degree_distribution = function(graph) {
  # calculate degree
  d = degree(graph, mode = "all")
  dd = degree.distribution(graph, mode = "all", cumulative = FALSE)
  degree = 1:max(d)
  probability = dd[-1]
  # delete blank values
  nonzero.position = which(probability != 0)
  probability = probability[nonzero.position]
  degree = degree[nonzero.position]
  # plot
  plot(probability ~ degree, log = "xy", xlab = "Degree (log)", ylab = "Probability (log)", 
       col = 1, main = "Degree Distribution")
  abline(lm(log10(probability) ~ log10(degree)))
}

plot_degree_distribution(df.y2h)
```

[image: log10-log10]

Comment: Thank you very much, I really apreciate your help. But other thing, how do you limit the tren line to the plot?? and how can I add the slope??

Comment: When you say “limit the tren “ do you mean removing certain data points (as in subset points to include only up to Degree<=20, for example)!and then plot regression line over those points only? This you can do with subsetting the data.

Comment: When you say “add slope” do you mean annotating the chart?

Comment: I mean limiting the line only to the plot, I'm getting this: https://imgur.com/a/xeAI1

Comment: Whit add slope I mean adding the slope/gradient of the trend line